# kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel return error by calling VTSessionSetProperty

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation

I'm trying to create a HEVC encode session based on VideoToolbox, the lines look like this:

```
/* create compression session */  
  VTCompressionSessionRef encoding_session;
  OSStatus status = VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, WIDTH, HEIGHT, kCMVideoCodecType_HEVC, NULL, NULL, NULL, onOneFrameEncoded, NULL, &encoding_session);


/* set properties */
  status = VTSessionSetProperty(encoding_session, kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel, kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel);
```

but the status = -12902 after `VTSessionSetProperty`, which means parameter error.
  actually it could encode the YUV420 8-bit raw data, but the syntax will be wrong as `bit_depth_luma_minus8 = 2`.

if I change to `kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main10_AutoLevel`, it returns OK, but as I know, Apply doesn't support 10-bit HEVC encoder so far, which makes me very confused.

I encountered this issue both on iOS(11.0 hardware encoder) and MacOS(10.13 software encoder), which causes decode errors.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I checked the syntax and it looks the macOS only support main10 profile.

Comment: the output stream format is kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr10BiPlanarFullRange